# snc/redis-bundle get redist cluster in controller - symfony 3+

Tags: symfony

I use "snc/redis-bundle": "3.0.0-RC1",

I update symfony 2.8 to 3.4

In controller I have

```
$redis_cluster = $this->container->get('snc_redis.cluster');

$cached = $redis_cluster->get($resOneCacheName)
```

get

```
The "snc_redis.cluster" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
```

How i can get redis service ?

Answer (score 0):

> stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

See https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html